# While(true) loop making my program not start up

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to make a SteamRE  bot which uses XNA, now, I just created a new XNA project, and slapped the SteamRE example code on it, if I run it, it works fine, but the thing is, it doesn't actually start up the XNA window, so it can't look for keyboard handling, etc.

If I remove the while(true) loop it works, but it won't connect.

Here is my code, if you guys could look at this and maybe help me out, it would be great.

```
namespace Steam
{
  public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
  {
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    string userName = "username";
    string passWord = "password";

    SteamClient steamClient = new SteamClient(); // initialize our client
    SteamUser steamUser;
    SteamFriends steamFriends;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        steamUser = steamClient.GetHandler<SteamUser>(); // we'll use this later to logon
        steamFriends = steamClient.GetHandler<SteamFriends>();

    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
    }

    KeyboardState oldState = Keyboard.GetState();

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        ConnectSteam();

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    public void ConnectSteam() 
    {
        steamClient.Connect(); // connect to the steam network

        while (true)
        {
            CallbackMsg msg = steamClient.WaitForCallback(true); // block and wait until a callback is posted

            msg.Handle<SteamClient.ConnectCallback>(callback =>
            {
                // the Handle function will call this lambda method for this callback

                if (callback.Result != EResult.OK)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed. 1");
                }
                //break; // the connect result wasn't OK, so something failed

                // we've successfully connected to steam3, so lets logon with our details
                Console.WriteLine("Connected to Steam3.");
                steamUser.LogOn(new SteamUser.LogOnDetails
                {
                    Username = userName,
                    Password = passWord,
                });
                Console.WriteLine("Logged on.");
            });
            msg.Handle<SteamUser.LogOnCallback>(callback =>
            {
                if (callback.Result != EResult.OK)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed. 2");
                }

                // we've now logged onto Steam3
            });
        }
    }

    public void ConnectToFPP() 
    {
        KeyboardState newState = Keyboard.GetState();  // get the newest state

        // handle the input
        if (oldState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Space) && newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
        {
            steamFriends.JoinChat(110338190871147670);
        }

        oldState = newState;  // set the new state as the old state for next time
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
  }
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: you use `while(true)` an infint loop, that blocks not only a window but program itself.

Comment: The Steam Client may be timing out, or there might be some other issues with the way you're blocking the thread and setting up callbacks. Is it possible to create an explicit timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as far as I see it is that, unless you need to constantly connect, you need to break out of your ConnectSteam code whenever you have actually connected.

```
Console.WriteLine("Logged on.");
break;
```

Or, you could have an isConnected variable (very pseudocod-ish):

```
bool isConnected = false
while(!isConnected)
{
    isConnected = LogonCode;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in XNA but I see that you are using `while(true)` loop inside `Update()` method of the window that have to deal with non scene, but window control update (actually even if the scene update nothing will be changed from this perspective).

You run into infinit loop trying to connect to some service. You run it on the same thread where window created so block window. 
I would suggest you use multithreading, so run the code where you're trying to connect in another thread. Use [`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbf0f1ct.aspx) or some other way of running threads and provide to the user information that program is connecting.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, the problem is in the `while(true)` fragment. Even if you succesfully connect, you never break out of the loop. Even with a `break;` after connecting would fix the issue, you'd still block the whole process from running until the connection is established.

The best solution is to remove the while and, once per frame (or second, or twice the wait time your asynchronous call uses), if the connection is not established, try **only once** to connect again. Since your connection code is asynchronous, your game will continue to cycle and you can keep drawing to the screen and notifying the user how things are going.

```
protected override void Update (GameTime gameTime)
{
    // ...
    if (!connected && !tryingToConnect)
    {
        ConnectSteam();

        // Remember to set to false once connection is established
        showConnectingDialog = true;
    } else
    {

    }
    // ...
}

protected override void Draw (GameTime gameTime)
{
    // ...
    if (showConnectingDialog)
    {
        SpriteBatch.DrawString(SpriteFont, "Connecting to Steam servers...", Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
    } else
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```